# Errors while trying to use pixray and diffvg

Tags: python, installation

There are plenty of errors for me when I try to use pixray, I have no idea what's how to fix any of them. I would appreciate some help. Here are the errors:

P.S. I tried installing diffvg for pixray, which didnt work so I just dumped all the contents into the same folder as the pixray(which I also dumped in due to it not installing) and my scripts.

```
2022-05-14 21:00:05.798493: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2022-05-14 21:00:05.798671: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
--> Not running with pydiffvg drawer support  cannot import name 'FilterType' from 'diffvg' (unknown location)
Using seed: 215713476432900
Downloading models/yfcc_2.pth from https://v-diffusion.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/yfcc_2.pth, please wait
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mathn\Desktop\Programming\Other\AI\BookWriting\ytConversion\youtube_conversion.py", line 24, in <module>
    gen_img("a happy frog")
  File "C:\Users\mathn\Desktop\Programming\Other\AI\BookWriting\ytConversion\youtube_conversion.py", line 6, in gen_img
    pxr.run(text, "vdiff", custom_loss="aesthetic", outdir="img")
  File "C:\Users\mathn\Desktop\Programming\Other\AI\BookWriting\ytConversion\pixray.py", line 2123, in run
    do_init(settings)
  File "C:\Users\mathn\Desktop\Programming\Other\AI\BookWriting\ytConversion\pixray.py", line 613, in do_init
    drawer.load_model(args, device)
  File "C:\Users\mathn\Desktop\Programming\Other\AI\BookWriting\ytConversion\vdiff.py", line 83, in load_model
    wget_file(model_urls[self.vdiff_model],checkpoint)
  File "C:\Users\mathn\Desktop\Programming\Other\AI\BookWriting\ytConversion\util.py", line 266, in wget_file
    output = subprocess.check_output(['wget', '-O', out, url])
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 424, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 505, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mathn\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\comtypes\client\_events.py", line 111, in error_printer
    return func(self, this, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\mathn\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\comtypes\_comobject.py", line 600, in IUnknown_Release
    _debug("%r.Release() -> %s", self, result)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1434, in debug
    self._log(DEBUG, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1589, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1599, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1661, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 952, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1186, in emit
    self.stream = self._open()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1175, in _open
    return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding,
NameError: name 'open' is not defined
Exception ignored on calling ctypes callback function: <function catch_errors.<locals>.call_with_this at 0x000002490A193B80>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mathn\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\comtypes\_comobject.py", line 97, in call_with_this
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1475, in error
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1589, in _log
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1599, in handle
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1661, in callHandlers
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 952, in handle
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1186, in emit
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1175, in _open
NameError: name 'open' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still working on this but it appears you're working on a local machine. I'll need some more information to help.
For example - where are your installation paths pointing.

As I understand it, your diffvg and pixray folders need to be separate but must be in the same workspace. Also, are you using the `--recursive` command when you update the submodules after cloning the repositories?

Here's a working example that you will also find in the docs:

```
!git clone --recursive https://github.com/pixray/pixray
!git clone https://github.com/pixray/diffvg
%cd diffvg
!git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Do try to have a look at the source code on the repositories as well.